# Is there a download limit to ios apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, app, rules-and-constraints

With reference to iOS 7.
I couldn't find any Apple documents with regards to this.

Are we able to download any size of documents and manage them ourselves (within our app say < 100MB)?
Example, we roll out new content every month. Thus after downloading contents for this month, we should remove last month's content to save space. Content doesn't have to be backed up and will be stored in Caches folder.

Comment: Have you tried emailing Apple support about this?

Comment: where is this data comming from?

Comment: @WorldEngineer nope I haven't.

Comment: @miraculixx it'll be from my own server.

Comment: @resting in this case I don't think there is a limit to how much data your app can download, except time limits on background processing or subject to the user keeping the app active while downloading (probably not a valid assumption). You might be able to overcome background limits by splitting the data into chunks, e.g. 5 seconds at a time.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any download or storage limits for your app (other than available space on the device, of course); if there were, they'd be mentioned in the [iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/). However, you do need to consider how your data files will work with iCloud -- in particular, you should decide whether it's okay for the device to discard your downloaded data when storage gets low.

If it's okay to remove your files, store them in the caches directory. If it's not okay, then you can store them in the documents directory and [set the attributes on your files to exclude them from iCloud backup](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html). Also, be sure to store user data separate from the downloaded data so that the user data can be backed up.

With so much data to download, you should consider using the new [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) network API so that you can [download data in a background session](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSessionConfiguration/backgroundSessionConfiguration%3a). This avoids the need to keep the app running while the data is being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is relative to the available storage on the device.  There exist (or did exist) Navigation apps that could download well over 1GB of data.